# how to add like button with a counter to my android app

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-sdk-3.0

I have wondered the facebook developers docs,

but saw only how to add "like action" and "likes counter"  to [html page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/).

I mean for the like counter saved in fb servers for that page.

How is it done in java for an android app?

Answer (score 0):

In Xml layout in which u have button, in button attribute add

```
android:onclick="like_counter";// this will call that method
```

in activity,
globally code this

```
int counter=0;

public int like_counter()
{
 counter++;
 return counter;
}
```

hope this is what u r asking...

Comment: I mean for the like counter saved in fb servers for that page.